# asp.net core OkObjectResult and IActionResult with unit test are not letting me loop over List - nested Result.Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mstest

I am trying to write a unit test with asp.net core in which the code I have looks like the following

```
[TestMethod]
public void NotificationController_should_return_notifications()
{
    //Act
    var controller = new NotificationsController(_dbContext, _logger);
    IActionResult actionResult = controller.Get();

    OkObjectResult okObjectResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;

    var model = okObjectResult.Value; //as List<Notification>;
```

When others do NOT have a paging object nested, they are able to just do

```
    var model = okObjectResultValue as TrainingMessages;
```

However, with my complex object, the model ends up being null as the collection is too complex with paging etc...

**What I want to do it just to get at the data that I SEE in the Watch**

```
okObjectResult.Value.Results[0].Id
```

**but this is not available to me, why?**

Here is the picture of the code and the WATCH
[image]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: In the VS watch, this works   okObjectResult.Value.Results[0].Id  , but not when I code it

Comment: Where does `okObjectResultValue` come from?

Comment: `var okObjectResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;`

Comment: I mean this line - `var model = okObjectResultValue as TrainingMessages;`. Where does the variable come from that makes them "able to do" this? And what specifically do you mean by "not have a paging object nested"?

Comment: so another person's unit test is unit TrainingMessages and they do not have a complex object with paging.   Theirs is very flat, so  `as TrainMessages` is a simple poco,  yet mine is simple poco of Notification wrapped inside a paging object as well  -  so I was hoping to loop over the OkObjectResult or instance of the actionResult

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested Result.Value and it's most likely because you're doing this:

[image]

My Create method calls the GetDashboard to return the newly inserted Dashboard. However, I'm returning an Ok(result) to an OK. So it's returning (Ok(Ok(result)).

**Solution** *(only return one Ok)*:

```
return await GetDashboard(dashboardId);
```